# Queries run fast separately, slowly under UNION

Tags: mysql

I had a query that was taking several minutes to run. I thought I might be able to get it to run faster as four separate queries, then a `UNION`. I was at least right about the four separate queries part. They run, from slowest to fastest, ~7 seconds, ~1 second, < 1 second and < 1 second.

So I would think that the `UNION` of all these would run, at the slowest, about 7 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10 seconds. However, when I run this `UNION` query, it takes over 100 seconds.

```
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_first_and_last_name)
union
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_full_name)
union
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_just_address)
union 
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_name_and_address)
```

Why would `UNION` make these all slower? It seems to me that all MySQL has to do is execute the four queries then concatenate the results.

**Edit**: I guess I didn't ask what I'm really after: a way to make this query run quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `union` removes duplicates. So it's not just about running the queries.

Try using `union all` instead of `union`.

That way, duplicates won't be removed:

```
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_first_and_last_name)
union all
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_full_name)
union all
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_just_address)
union all
(select id from view_macatawa_prospect_match_name_and_address)
```

With `union all` you should get times closer to what you've got when you run the queries separately.

Comment: It's still just as slow with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'UNION ALL' instead

UNION tries apply 'DISTINCT' implicitly, meaning your results will not have any duplicates hence the slowdown. If you dont want the implicit DISTINCT you can use UNION ALL.